# Scikit-learn make_scorer custom metric problem for multiclass clasification

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, make-scorer

I am doing a churn analysis. I used

```
randomcv = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=clf,param_distributions = params_grid,
                          cv=kfoldcv,n_iter=100, n_jobs=-1, scoring='roc_auc')
```

and everything was fine, but then, I tried with a custom scoring function this way

```
def gain_fn(y_true, y_prob):
    tp = np.where((y_prob>=0.025) & (y_true==1), 40000, 0)
    fp = np.where((y_prob>=0.025) & (y_true==0), -1000, 0)
    return np.sum([tp,fp])

scorer_fn = make_scorer(gain_fn, greater_is_better = True, needs_proba=True)

randomcv = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=clf,param_distributions = params_grid,
                          cv=kfoldcv,n_iter=100, n_jobs=-1, scoring=scorer_fn)
```

but I want to make a calculation inside of gain_fn with a certain value of the class (it has 3 possible values). How to select the correct y_pred parameter? Any suggestion? Thank you!

Comment: I get nonzero results for the `load_breast_cancer` dataset from sklearn.  Maybe your problem is sufficiently imbalanced that the default cutoff of 0.5 never gives positive predictions even for different hyperparameters?  Does it work without the `RandomizedSearchCV`, with just default hyperparameters say?

Comment: you are SO right! I have to use probabilities.

Comment: cross-posted at https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/100607/55122

Comment: Yes, I am sorry, I was not sure where was the right place to put it. Thank you

Comment: While determining where it should live I don't personally mind keeping it in both, but linking them together is important to prevent duplication of effort.